# Compare values based on common keys in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi, I have two data frames. Both with two columns, identifier and weight.

What I would like is, for each "key" so A and B, if the second column have opposite signs accross the two dataframes (so one is positive and one is negative, then create a new column with the lowest absolute value).

```
    import pandas as pd
    A = {"ID":["A", "B"], "Weight":[500,300]}
    B = {"ID":["A", "B"], "Weight":[-300,100]}

    dfA = pd.DataFrame(data=A)
    dfB = pd.DataFrame(data=B)

    dfC = dfA.merge(dfB, how='outer', left_on=['ID'], right_on=['ID'])
```

So expected output would be a new column on dfC with the lowest absolute value between both weight columns if they have an opposite signs

Comment: How are those dataframes? Please provide a [mcve] with data and/or  code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I added the code in, let me know if more is needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get the result you want, using df.apply and df.concat
Step 1 : Create dfC with ID, WeightA and WeightB

```
import numpy as np
A = dfA.set_index('ID')
B = dfB.set_index('ID')
dfC = pd.concat([A,B], 1).reset_index()
dfC.columns = ['ID', 'WeightA', 'WeightB']
```

Edit : 
You can use your dfC too, just rename the columns as such and use the Step2 for your result.

```
dfC = dfA.merge(dfB, how='outer', left_on=['ID'], right_on=['ID'])
dfC.columns = ['ID', 'WeightA', 'WeightB']
```

Step2: Create column 'lowestAbsWeight' which is the lowest absolute of the two weights A and B

```
dfC['lowestAbsWeight'] = dfC.apply(lambda row: np.absolute(row['WeightA']) if np.absolute(row['WeightA'])<np.absolute(row['WeightB'] )  else np.absolute(row['WeightB']), axis=1  )
```

The output looks like:

```
    ID  WeightA WeightB lowestAbsWeight
0   A   500     -300          300
1   B   300      100          100
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way via `.loc` accessor:

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = dfA.set_index('ID')
dfB = dfB.set_index('ID')

dfC = dfA.copy()
dfC['Result'] = 0

mask = (dfA['Weight'] > 0) != (dfB['Weight'] > 0)

dfC.loc[mask, 'Result'] = np.minimum(dfA['Weight'].abs(), dfB['Weight'].abs())

dfC = dfC.reset_index()

#   ID  Weight  Result
# 0  A     500     300
# 1  B     300       0
```